# SublimeLinter JSHint "Missing space after 'function'" on SL3 is not enabled

Tags: jshint, sublimelinter

I don't know why many things on my JSHint are not enabled. For instance, I do want to see the warning for missing space after 'function' warning, but I don't!

My `.jshintrc` looks as:

```
{
    "white": true,
    "node": true,
    "browser": true,
    "es5": true,
    "esnext": true,
    "bitwise": true,
    "camelcase": false,
    "curly": true,
    "eqeqeq": true,
    "immed": true,
    "indent": 4,
    "latedef": "nofunc",
    "newcap": true,
    "noarg": true,
    "quotmark": "single",
    "regexp": true,
    "undef": true,
    "unused": true,
    "strict": true,
    "trailing": true,
    "smarttabs": true,
    "globals" : {
        "define"  : false,
        "angular" : false,
        "_"       : false,
        "$"       : false,
        "jQuery"  : false,
        "moment"  : false
    }
}
```